# Python & cURL status 403, only Postman gets 200 (IP based)

Tags: python, rest, curl, python-requests

I got a really weird problem, I have been struggling with all day:
I want to consume a REST-api. The API can only be accessed while I'm logged into a VPN as the API can only be called from one specifc IP.

Using Postman I can consume the api perfectly fine. If do do everthing correctly, I get status 200, if I mess up authentication, I get status 401 and if I try to consume the API without being logged into the VPN I get status 403.

I then tried to automize the API calls by using python. I also tried defining a "User-Agent" which didn't help.

```
import requests
url = ""# I removed the url for this example
token=""# I removed the token for this example
headers = \
{
    "accept": "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true",
    "Authorization" : f"Bearer {token}"
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Now the really confusing stuff starts: Assuming I somehow managed to make a mistake in the Python implementation, I tried consuming the API using curl. The Swagger documentation even had a copy paste example for cURL. Result: Error 403, access forbidden. This is weired. Being logged into the VPN I should have at least gotten Error 401 (as I did using Postman with a wrong authentication).

Then I just copied the url into a browser (Edge and Chrome). As expected and hoped: Error 401 (as I couldn't specify the header for authentication). Then out of desperation I tried calling the API using selenium and I got Error 403.

Nothing of that makes sense to me. What does Postman do differently than cURL? Why does calling the url using a browser work, but not using a "virtualized" browser with selenium?
I assume it must be some configuration problem on my side. It somehow seems as if cURL and Python bypassed the VPN. I don't even know if that's possible. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Trace the message as sent by postman

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the idea about tracing the message. Turns out that Postman somehow provided a proxy. I don't know where it got the proxy information from, but providing the exact same proxy was actually the solution.

Postman also can convert requests to cURL requests, however it didn't include the proxy.